# Read specific data from text file and assign value to different variables

Tags: java, text-files

I have to read a text file containing the following data-

```
1001-01-171714 Lewis CS 699 
1002-01-771424 Lewis CS 477
1003-01-141434 Jones MATH 698
1004-01-141444 Jones CS 617
1005-01-141454 Brown CHEM 326
1006-01-141464 Jones BIO 127
1007-01-771474 Sanders CS 998
```

I have to assign these values to different variables such as "isbn","author", "field", "coursenum". These variables are present in a class called Book. I have to create another class called BookCollection whose constructor will-read the data, assign to variables, add the book object to an array present in BookCollection. My question is how to exactly read the data and assign it to **SPECIFIC** variables from a constructor in another class, keeping in mind this "book has to be added to the array. **I know how to read inputs, but I am confused on the assigning each lines' different data to different book object's variables.**

Comment: try to use a `CSV` reader. it will read line by line, transfer each link to a java object, and return an array.

Comment: @benLawry I'm sorry, but I am utterly confused with this question. And this is just the base code, I understand the stuff that has to be added to this. But I can't grasp this base piece of code.

Comment: @Udy I have to code in Blue J and show it in clas, so I can't use any other software.

Comment: start by writing a method that parser a single line to the desire object, then iterate on each line ,use the above method and add the returned object to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode for you:

Read a line, saving it to string "yourString"

```
String yourString = //however you want to read your line;
```

Separate it into 4 sections, using a " " character with this function, 
 `public String[] split(String regex)`, like so

```
String[] x = yourString.split(" ");
```

Call constructor:

```
Book y = new Book(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]);
```

Add to the array, or arraylist or whatever list you choose to use at the end.

```
Array[i] = y;
```